# What's the C# equivalent function of select/epoll/kqueue?

Tags: c#, sockets

All I want is to read from multiple sockets (less than 10) at the same time. No matter which socket has something to read, I'll read and warp the data into a message and put that message into a queue.

It's easy to do so with, for example, `select()`. I can just add those sockets (less than 10) to a `FD_SET` and `select()` on that set. How can I do that in C#? The simpler the solution is, the better.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx)

Comment: @ja_mesa +1 & Thanks! That really looks promising! I will accept your answer if you would make one :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [ja_mesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733070/ja-mesa) you are looking for the [Socket.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx).